# Is the expression »Er hat unser Leben beeinflusst wie kaum ein anderer« correct?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-order

Er hat unser Leben beeinflusst wie kaum ein anderer

Comment: Konrad Zuse hat den Computer entwickelt, Also  Er hat unser Leben beeinflusst wie kaum ein anderer , aber sein Name ist nicht so bekannt, wie er sein sollte.

Comment: Konrad Zuse hat den Computer entwickelt, aber sein Name ist nicht so bekannt, wie er sein sollte.
Also , Er hat unser Leben beeinflusst wie kaum ein anderer .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. "Er hat unser Leben beeinflusst wie kaum ein anderer" is a correct German sentence.